# ¡Como Generar un PDF en python manteniendo estructura de un texto?

Tags: python, pdf, ocr

Estoy elaborando un programa ocr, y deseo mantener el formato que obtengo de salida con la variable que contiene todo el texto que extraigo de la imágenes.

Respuesta por consola

[image]

generando un archivo txt

[image]

respuesta pdf

[image]

```
archivoAppend  =  open("ejemplo.html", "a");
addText = archivoAppend.write(text);

archivoAppend.close();

from xhtml2pdf import pisa
import os




 base_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
 sourceHtml = open(os.path.join(base_dir, 'A:/laragon/www/APASE/ocr_api/ejemplo.html')).read()
 outputFilename = "test.pdf"

 def convertHtmlToPdf(sourceHtml, outputFilename):
      resultFile = open(outputFilename, "w+b")
      pisaStatus = pisa.CreatePDF(
        sourceHtml,
        dest=resultFile)
     resultFile.close()
     return pisaStatus.err
 if __name__=="__main__":
     pisa.showLogging()
     convertHtmlToPdf(sourceHtml, outputFilename)
```

El código anterior genera el pdf pero no mantiene la estructura que me da la respuesta como se muestra en la imagen de la consola o el archivo txt.

Hay una librería diferente que pueda utilizar y ue resuelva el inconveninete, o como pudiera resolverlo con las herramientas que ya estoy utilizando.

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: No se ven las imagenes ...

Comment: Creo que la solución más sencilla, ya que estás pasando por html para convertir en pdf el texto, es insertar un `<pre>`/`</pre>` al inicio y final de tu texto, para que en HTML se vea "preformateado" (como si fuera código).